# MATLAB: Concatenating table rows when equal values in column 2 AND 3

Tags: matlab, datatable

is there any fancy way on concatenating values in a matlab table based on conditions w/o using a loop?
I need to sum up the values in column 1 when the values in column 2 and 3 are identically.

Example: table rows 8-12 and row 14 in table `T_allC` have the same value `15` in column 2 and `15597` in column 3. All values in column 1 needs to be summarized to `900`. The number of table rows would be reduced as well.

Thanks a lot!

|  | 1 Count | 2 Range | 3 Mean |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 75 | 11 | 15 |
| 2 | 75 | 11 | 9 |
| 3 | 75 | 12 | 62 |
| 4 | 100 | 11 | 502 |
| 5 | 150 | 12 | 8001 |
| 6 | 75 | 14 | 15 |
| 7 | 2000 | 15 | 1278 |
| 8 | 150 | 15 | 15597 |
| 9 | 150 | 15 | 15597 |
| 10 | 150 | 15 | 15597 |
| 11 | 150 | 15 | 15597 |
| 12 | 150 | 15 | 15597 |
| 13 | 150 | 15 | 15661 |
| 14 | 150 | 15 | 15597 |
| 15 | 150 | 15 | 15661 |
| 16 | 100 | 16 | 1268 |
| 17 | 100 | 16 | 1313 |
| 18 | 150 | 16 | 15661 |

Comment: It looks like [`groupsummary`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.groupsummary.html) should help. Please don't post images of data (or code).

Comment: It can also be done with [`findgroups`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findgroups.html) and [`splitapply`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/splitapply.html)

Comment: @beaker, `G = groupsummary(T_allC,["Mean","Range"],"sum","Count")` did the trick. Thanks a lot! Post it as answer to be able to vote for you.

Comment: @JFS Feel free to post an answer if you like.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `varfun`, by specifying the variables to group on (`GroupingVariables`) and the variables to operate on (`InputVariables`), with the function to apply (in this case `@sum`.

```
T = varfun( @sum, T_allC, 'GroupingVariables', {'Range','Mean'}, 'InputVariables', 'Count' );
```

You might want to remove the default `GroupCount` column which tells you the number of rows from the original table combined in the output table

```
T.GroupCount = [];
```

[image: table output]

This is very similar to `groupsummary`, but I like the explicit name-value syntax which specifies the grouping/input variables.